# Concatenate strings and replace variables in the string with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Does underscore.js have a way to concatenate strings and replace variables in them? Ie, similar to c++ `sprintf()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Underscore.js extension: http://gabceb.github.io/underscore.string.site/